# EmberJS How to capture enter key in login form

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm new to EmberJS/Handlebars and I have a login form that I'd like the user to be able to submit via the enter key. What's the proper way to capture that event and submit my form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. Here's what I did:

I found a handlebars attribute insert-newline='[functionCall]' that filters the enter key.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I know 2 ways:

1. Follow **HTML standard**.

Use `<form> {{input type='submit' action='submitForm'}} </form>`.
Remember to use `event.preventDefault()` in `submitForm`, or it will redirect to form's action property (or refresh current page if you didn't set any).

2. Use **keydown/keyup** event in every form elements that you want to trigger enter (well, this is really a bad idea, but it works):

Template.hbs

```
{{input type='textbox' key-up='submitForm'}}
```

Controller.js

```
 export default Ember.Controller.extend({
   actions: {
     submitForm(value, event) {
       if (event.keyCode === 13) {
         // Do something here
       }
     }
   }
 });
```